# laravel change object when use groupBy in collection

Tags: php, laravel

when i use groupBy with laravel

i use it for api but response show like this example

```
$data = Order::where('id_user',Auth::id())->with('resturant')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()->groupBy('uuid');
      return response()->json([
            'data'=>$dataa,
            'state'=>true,
        ]);
```

response showing

```
"data": {
    "11447": [
        {
            "id": 75704,
            "uuid": "11447",
            ...........
            "resturant": {
                "id": 5,
                "category_id": 1,
                ...........
            }
        }
    ],
    "49262": [
        {
            "id": 75702,
            "uuid": "49262",
            ...........
            "resturant": {
                "id": 5,
                "category_id": 1,
               ...........
            }
        },
    ]
},
"state": true
```

}

i need remove number in object

"11447": [

how  ?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to index count from json in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60748842/how-to-index-count-from-json-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

please use this

```
$data = Order::select(DB::raw('id,uuid,count(*) as count_order'))->groupBy('uuid')->get();
  return response()->json([
        'data'=>$data,
        'state'=>true,
    ]);
```

Comment: There may be several rows for each uuid, Can you tell me why you want to use GroupBy?

Comment: in table in databes order food  in multi table by food order number "uuid" when i nedd show for user orders i use groupby uuid-> nummer order

Comment: i change my answer  - can you test it ?

Comment: you should add DB  --> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Comment: but i need add join left with resturant info

Comment: use with('resturant') and and resturants.* in select

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with() !

Comment: Order::with()->select()->groupBy()->get()

Comment: $data = Order::with('resturant')->select(DB::raw('uuid'))->where('id_user',Auth::id())->groupBy('uuid')->get();  but return null in json array , when i put it in select return error

Comment: in select you should use  "orders.id,orders.uuid,count(orders.id) as count_order,resturants.*"

Comment: $data = Order::where('id_user',Auth::id())->with('resturant')->select('orders.id,orders.uuid,count(orders.id) as count_order ,resturants.*')->groupBy('uuid')->get();
it's right ?